# angular form how to make input and button have same values when get values

Tags: angular, typescript, forms

I have problem where when modal out, I try input with button all my form, the result is out great. But when I try input with button then edit with input form all the values is gone.

What I suspect right now is button have different values with Input right now but I don't know how to make it same values input for both of it.

This is the code with ts

```js
public target: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
  time: new FormControl(0),
  state_of_charge: new FormControl(0),
  energy: new FormControl(0),
});

public clickButtonNum(num: number) {
  this.target.value.time = num
}
public clickButtonSoc(num: number) {
  this.target.value.state_of_charge = num
}
public clickButtonEnergy(num: number) {
  this.target.value.energy = num
}

public clickModal() {
  const backdrop = document.getElementById('drop')
  if (backdrop != null) {
    backdrop.classList.add('modal-backdrop');
  }
}

public closed() {
  this.dialogRef.close();
}

public clickModalClose() {
  const backdrop = document.getElementById('drop')


  if (backdrop != null) {
    backdrop.classList.remove('modal-backdrop');
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- modal -->
<div class="flex flex-col w-full justify-center my-1" *ngIf="status === 'Preparing'">
  <!-- info target -->
  <div>
    <label *ngIf="target.value.time" class="text-md mt-2 font-medium">Time : {{target.value.time}} <span>minutes</span> </label>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="isDC === 'DC'">
    <label *ngIf="target.value.state_of_charge" class="text-md mt-2 font-medium">SoC : {{target.value.state_of_charge}} <span>%</span> </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label *ngIf="target.value.energy" class="text-md mt-2 font-medium mb-2">Energy : {{target.value.energy}} <span>kWh</span></label>
  </div>
  <!-- /info target -->
  <div class="flex flex-row mt-2 justify-center" *ngIf="isOnline">
    <button translate class="button-input bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-700 text-white font-xl py-2 px-6 rounded-md mb-2 shadow-lg" (click)="clickModal()" (click)="myDialog.show()">Target Time</button>
    <button translate class="button-input bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-700 text-white font-xl py-2 px-8 rounded-md mb-2 shadow-lg" (click)="target.reset()">Reset</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /modal -->

<!-- Time -->
<dialog class="modal-content rounded-md" #myDialog>
  <form class="p-1" [formGroup]="target">
    <div translate class="mb-2 flex justify-between">Target Time<span translate>(minutes)</span>
      <button class="close rounded-xl w-5 bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-600 text-white shadow-md" (click)="clickModalClose()" (click)="myDialog.close()">X</button>
    </div>
    <button (click)="clickButtonNum(0)" class="bg-green-400 hover:bg-green-300 cursor-pointer w-10 h-10 rounded-md mx-2 shadow-md">
        0
      </button>
    <button (click)="clickButtonNum(60)" class="bg-green-400 hover:bg-green-300 cursor-pointer w-10 h-10 rounded-md mx-2 shadow-md">
        60
      </button>
    <button (click)="clickButtonNum(120)" class="bg-green-400 hover:bg-green-300 cursor-pointer w-10 h-10 rounded-md mx-2 shadow-md">
        120
      </button>
    <button (click)="clickButtonNum(180)" class="bg-green-400 hover:bg-green-300 cursor-pointer w-10 h-10 rounded-md mx-2 shadow-md">
        180
      </button>
    <div>
      <input class="border-2 mt-3 w-full px-3 py-1 rounded-md text-black" formControlName="time" [value]="target.value.time" type="number" placeholder="{{ 'time charging on minutes' | translate }}" />
    </div>

    <!-- SoC -->
    <div translate class="mb-2 flex justify-between">Battery Target <span translate>(%)</span>
    </div>
    <button (click)="clickButtonSoc(0)" class="bg-green-400 hover:bg-green-300 cursor-pointer w-10 h-10 rounded-md mx-2 shadow-md">
        0
      </button>
    <button (click)="clickButtonSoc(30)" class="bg-green-400 hover:bg-green-300 cursor-pointer w-10 h-10 rounded-md mx-2 shadow-md">
        30
      </button>
    <button (click)="clickButtonSoc(60)" class="bg-green-400 hover:bg-green-300 cursor-pointer w-10 h-10 rounded-md mx-2 shadow-md">
        60
      </button>
    <button (click)="clickButtonSoc(80)" class="bg-green-400 hover:bg-green-300 cursor-pointer w-10 h-10 rounded-md mx-2 shadow-md">
        80
      </button>
    <div>
      <input class="border-2 mt-3 w-full px-3 py-1 rounded-md text-black" formControlName="state_of_charge" [value]="target.value.state_of_charge" type="number" placeholder="{{ 'battery (%)' | translate }}" />
    </div>

    <!-- Energy -->

    <div translate class="mb-2 flex justify-between">Energy Target<span translate>(kWh)</span>
    </div>
    <button (click)="clickButtonEnergy(0)" class="bg-green-400 hover:bg-green-300 cursor-pointer w-10 h-10 rounded-md mx-2 shadow-md">
        0
      </button>
    <button (click)="clickButtonEnergy(10)" class="bg-green-400 hover:bg-green-300 cursor-pointer w-10 h-10 rounded-md mx-2 shadow-md">
        10
      </button>
    <button (click)="clickButtonEnergy(20)" class="bg-green-400 hover:bg-green-300 cursor-pointer w-10 h-10 rounded-md mx-2 shadow-md">
        20
      </button>
    <button (click)="clickButtonEnergy(80)" class="bg-green-400 hover:bg-green-300 cursor-pointer w-10 h-10 rounded-md mx-2 shadow-md">
        80
      </button>
    <div>
      <input class="border-2 mt-3 w-full px-3 py-1 rounded-md text-black" formControlName="energy" [value]="target.value.energy" type="number" placeholder="{{ 'energy charging / kW' | translate }}" />
    </div>
  </form>

  <button class="button-ok" role="button" (click)="clickModalClose()" (click)="myDialog.close()">Ok</button>
</dialog>
```

Comment: can you give an example of the inputs data and outputs you are expecting, if you can share your code on stackblitz it will be  useful

Comment: what i expecting if i press 30 on button, on input out 30 but when i edit 30 to 20 i want all input not gone

ex
first hit 20 button
*input show 20
then edit to 10

what I want is when edit stay become to 10 edited
*what happend right now, edit 10 all other input gone